# configuration only auth in Wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

i m new learner for wso2

wso2 - oauth, user Management and my other service available in  predix.

so i have used wso2 identity server for oauth and user management.

Problem :

1) how to integrate predix(idp)

2) how to used this things using REST API

Comment: Couldn't understand the second question. What do you need to achieve using REST APIs?

Comment: @user3686193 second question related to how to handle total process using rest api bcz if we will integrate federate identity so that is redirect to login console and after that redirect to mention redirected url.
can it possible total process using single endpoint?

Comment: Did you need REST API to configure federated IDP? I couldn't understand what you mean by 'handle total process'. Are you referring to the OAuth endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I understood that you need to integrate the mentioned Idp as federated Identity Provider in WSO2 Identity Server. Doc - https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Federated+Authentication guides the steps to configure federated authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, WSO2 IS don't have a build in authenticator for the Prefix. But as the Prefix support OIDC flow, you should be able to WSO2 OIDC federated authenticator. Steps can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=50514076)

I haven't got the chance to test with Prefix. But it needs to work